# MVC5 Controller: Check for duplicate in DB before saving?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, linq, controller

On my `View` I have a button I use to submit a `[description]` value to my `Controller` via JSON, which is then used to create a new `Table` record. For example:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult createNewStatus(string description)
    {
        INV_Statuses status = new INV_Statuses()
        {
            // ID auto-set during save
            status_description = description,
            created_date = DateTime.Now,
            created_by = System.Environment.UserName
        };

        //var allErrors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(x => x.Errors);

        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.INV_Statuses.Add(status);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
        }

        return Json(new { ID = status.Id, Text = status.status_description }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

What I'd like to do now (before saving the Status to the DB) is run a check to see if any other records in the `INV_Statuses` table have a `[description]` value matching the one submitted to the function for new creation. If there is a match, I want to return an `error/validation?` message and alert the user the submitted value already exists and to choose it from the `DropDownList` on the View.

Can anyone provide an example of how to go about this with LINQ in my MVC Controller?

---

**EDIT**: Added my `View` JS code for submitting the new Status:

```
        $('#createNewStatus').click(function () {
            $('#createStatusFormContainer').show();
        })

        $('#cancelNewStatus').click(function () {
            $('#createStatusFormContainer').hide();
        })

        $('#submitNewStatus').click(function () {
            var form = $(this).closest('form');
            var data = { description: document.getElementById('textNewStatus').value };

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "JSON",
                url: '@Url.Action("createNewStatus", "INV_Assets")',
                data: data,
                success: function (resp) {
                    $('#selectStatus').append($('<option></option>').val(resp.ID).text(resp.Text));
                    form[0].reset();
                    $('#createStatusFormContainer').hide();
                    var count = $('#selectStatus option').size();
                    $("#selectStatus").prop('selectedIndex', count - 1);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("ERROR!");
                }
            });
        });
```

---

**EDIT2**:

Adricadar's suggestion:

```
        INV_Statuses status = new INV_Statuses()
        {
            // ID auto-set during save
            status_description = description,
            created_date = DateTime.Now,
            created_by = System.Environment.UserName
        };

        try
        {
            var existingStatus = db.INV_Statuses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.status_description.ToUpper() == status.status_description.ToUpper());
            var isDuplicateDescription = existingStatus != null;

            if (isDuplicateDescription)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "[" + status.status_description + "] already exists in the database. Please select from the DropDownList.");
            }
            else if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.INV_Statuses.Add(status);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
        }

        return Json(new { ID = status.Id, Text = status.status_description }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

I added a `.ToUpper()` in my comparison in Controller, but even though the match with `.ToUpper()` gets identified, the `ModelState.AddModelError()` code fires, then the code returns and no error message is issued?

The value (though duplicate) still gets added to the dropdownlist (visually, not in DB) via my current JS code:

```
        $('#createNewStatus').click(function () {
            $('#createStatusFormContainer').show();
        })

        $('#cancelNewStatus').click(function () {
            $('#createStatusFormContainer').hide();
        })

        $('#submitNewStatus').click(function () {
            var form = $(this).closest('form');
            var data = { description: document.getElementById('textNewStatus').value };

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "JSON",
                url: '@Url.Action("createNewStatus", "INV_Assets")',
                data: data,
                success: function (resp) {
                    $('#selectStatus').append($('<option></option>').val(resp.ID).text(resp.Text));
                    form[0].reset();
                    $('#createStatusFormContainer').hide();
                    var count = $('#selectStatus option').size();
                    $("#selectStatus").prop('selectedIndex', count - 1);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("ERROR!");
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to add a unique constraint on your table, and catch the resulting error when you try to insert it.  Or you need to look for it first, but I'm a firm believer in the database enforcing what it can, as the next application that tries to use that table may try and insert a duplicate.

Comment: @RobertMcKee, That's a good idea. Any thoughts on how to implement a Unique constraint on my table field (Ex.) `[status_description]`? I'm currently using a local `DbMigrationsConfiguration<InventoryTracker.DAL.InventoryTrackerContext>` through Code-First development, but in PROD will be referencing tables in ORACLE.

Comment: Sorry, you'd need to ask someone else, I always do Database First.

Answer (score 1):

Check for existing status and set status back as follows:

```
var existingStatus = db.INV_Statuses.FirstOrDefault(s => s.status_description == description);

if (existingStatus ==null)
{
   db.INV_Statuses.Add(status);
   db.SaveChanges();
}
else 
{ 
   // set the status back to existing
   status = existingStatus;   
}
```

Set an existing flag in your response:

```
return Json(new { ID = status.Id, Text = status.status_description, AlreadyExists = (existingStatus != null)  }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Then in your response JavaScript, simply parse out the returned data:

```
success: function (resp) {

if (resp.AlreadyExists != true)
{
     $('#selectStatus').append($('<option></option>').val(resp.ID).text(resp.Text));
     form[0].reset();
     $('#createStatusFormContainer').hide();
     var count = $('#selectStatus option').size();
     $("#selectStatus").prop('selectedIndex', count - 1);
      }
      else
      {
         alert(resp.status_description + " already exists");
         $("#selectStatus").val(resp.Id);
      }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot. I think there is a typo/missed closing-parentheses on your `return Json` segment, but I'm not quite sure where.

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic Sorry, I see typo now, there may be more as there is no compiler in the browser window. :)

Comment: Hmm... I'm a little confused about how best to structure the code in the controller I currently have with the additions you've suggested? Currently I have the `existingStatus` variable checked, and if `null`/`Model.IsValid` I save the status. `Else` I set `status = existingStatus` and then do the return. How would I handle the return exactly given my JSON return on my view with `resp` check for `success/error`? (Adding in EDIT). I guess I'm just confused about how the `existingStatus` is used in relation to `success/error` on the return to view?

Answer (score 1):

You can query the database for a status with an existing description and if exists and an model state error.

Be aware that string comparison is **case sensitive**.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult createNewStatus(string description)
{
    INV_Statuses status = new INV_Statuses()
    {
        // ID auto-set during save
        status_description = description,
        created_date = DateTime.Now,
        created_by = System.Environment.UserName
    };

    //var allErrors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(x => x.Errors);

    try
    {
        var existingStatus = db.INV_Statuses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.status_description.ToUpper() == status.status_description.ToUpper());
        var isDuplicateDescription = existingStatus != null;

        string error = String.Empty;
        if (isDuplicateDescription)
        {
           error = "[" + status.status_description + "] already exists in the database. Please select from the DropDownList.";
        }
        else if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.INV_Statuses.Add(status);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
    }

    return Json(new { ID = status.Id, Text = status.status_description, Error = error , IsDuplicate = isDuplicateDescription }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

In `javascript` verify if response have `IsDuplicate = true` if is true you skip the part where you need to add an element in dropdown.

```
    $('#createNewStatus').click(function () {
        $('#createStatusFormContainer').show();
    })

    $('#cancelNewStatus').click(function () {
        $('#createStatusFormContainer').hide();
    })

    $('#submitNewStatus').click(function () {
        var form = $(this).closest('form');
        var data = { description: document.getElementById('textNewStatus').value };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",
            url: '@Url.Action("createNewStatus", "INV_Assets")',
            data: data,
            success: function (resp) {
                if(resp.IsDuplicate)
                {
                     //display error from response
                     //display resp.Error
                } else {
                    $('#selectStatus').append($('<option></option>').val(resp.ID).text(resp.Text));
                    form[0].reset();
                    $('#createStatusFormContainer').hide();
                    var count = $('#selectStatus option').size();
                    $("#selectStatus").prop('selectedIndex', count - 1);
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("ERROR!");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks adricadar. I tried your suggestion, but ran into some weird behavior. Please see my EDIT2.

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic i saw your edit2, you get duplicate record on dropdown because you didn't check in `javascript` to see if it's duplicate description. See my edited `C#` code, and `Javascript`